# Erro de conversão no array de um ficheiro .csv para uma datatable

Tags: c#

Tou tentado passar os dados de um ficheiro .csv para uma datatable e o código parece estar tudo ok mas estou aqui de volta de este erro há bastante tempo e não sei como resolvê-lo.

Tenho duas colunas no meu ficheiro .csv e uma tipo string outra tipo inteiro 
e o erro pelo o que percebi tá a dar na primeira linha em que o "ATID" não é inteiro nessa primeira linha sendo que as restantes é um numero inteiro e não sei como resolver agradecia ajuda. Já tentei fazer conversões e não resultou (posso ter feito errado, alguma ajuda é bem vinda).

**Exemplo:**

PPID ; ATID

asd ;  1

asd ; 2

asd ;  3

dsa ;  4

erf ;   5

**Erro:** System.ArgumentException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.Couldn't store <#assetId#> in AtId Column.  Expected type is Int32.'

Código:

```
     using (StreamReader sr = new 
     StreamReader(@"C:Pathfile....csv"))
        {
            var datatable = new DataTable();
            datatable.Columns.Add("PPId", typeof(string));
            datatable.Columns.Add("AtId", typeof(int));
            string line;


                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line + "\n");
                    string[] lineitems = line.Split(";");
                    DataRow dr = datatable.NewRow();
                    dr["PPId"] = lineitems[0];
                    dr["AtId"] = lineitems[1]; 
                    datatable.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

        }
```

[image: Erro/Debug]

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fazer um **cast** na linha onde salva o valor no datatable para que salve no formato correto.

O código ficará assim:

```
dr["AtId"] = (int) lineitems[1];
```

Sugiro fazer um tratamento caso ocorram erros no casting.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/klc4kg, que tipo de tratamento estás a falar ao certo , eu sou beginner em c#  e tou aprendendo, como poderia fazer esse tratamento face a esse erro pois tenho o lineitems definido como string

Comment: Tentar usar assim: dr["AtId"] = Convert.ToInt32(lineitems[1]);

Comment: http://prntscr.com/klfa7u , keeps trowing the error xd, i already tryed that before but didnt work, i realy dont know how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Usando uma verificação com `tryParse` é possível verificar isso antes do erro:

```
while (true)
{
         string[] lineItems = line.Split(';');

         if (int.TryParse(lineItems[1], out int result))
         {
                //So entrará aqui se o valor puder ser convertido. Caso sim, pode já usar a variavel com nome result, criada acima
         }
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou , coloquei esse comando dentro do while , mas ele continua a ler a primeira linha, vou postar screenshot http://prntscr.com/klc34b

Comment: Modifiquei a resposta, só adaptar para o seu caso agora. Assim não terá erro, pois somente tentará usar o valor caso o tryParse retornar true. Veja se te atende agora.